# Would this "on-fly" passing object suffer of memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, std

I'm creating (allocating) "on-fly" a complex number while passing it to an `exp()` function. Whole code:

```
std::complex<double> resZeros(0.0, 0.0);
resZeros = a0 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -0 * freq * 2 * M_PI));
```

Will this introduce memory leak? In fact I don't manually destroy `std::complex<double>(0.0, -0 * freq * 2 * M_PI)`.

Or is `std::complex` smart enough to delete it when its out of scope?

Comment: If you didn't create it with new, you don't need to delete it.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote: there's nothing wrong with clearing up personal confusion via a well written question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that's fine: `std::complex<double>(0.0, -0 * freq * 2 * M_PI)` is an *anonymous temporary* and the C++ standard is very specific in saying that it "lives" for as long as the statement; conceptually the destructor to `std::complex` is called just after the assignment to `resZeros`.

**Anonymous temporaries do not cause memory leaks.**